# Can I have one million tables in my database?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, social-networking

Would there be any advantages/disadvantages to having one million tables in my database.

I am trying to implement comments. So far, I can think of two ways to do this:
1. Have all comments from all posts in 1 table.
2. Have a separate table for each post and store all comments from that post in it's respective table.

Which one would be better?

Thanks

Comment: The first one. Good luck trying to manage your database with a table per post - that's crazy. I'll add a bit more useful information. You should have a table for posts and a table for comments. Database engines are built to handle massive amounts of data efficiently, and as long as you add indexes on the post_id columns etc then you shouldn't experience much in the way of trouble/delay/response time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* have a million tables but this might not be ideal for a number of reasons[*]. Classical RDBMS are typically deployed & optimised for storing millions/billions of rows in hundreds/thousands of tables.

As for the problem you're trying to solve, as others state, use foreign keys to relate a pair of tables: posts & comments a la [MySQL syntax]:

```
create table post(id integer primary key, post text);
create table comment(id integer primary key, postid integer , comment text, key fk (postid));
```

{you can add constraints to enforce referential integrity between comment and posts to avoid orphaned comments but this requires certain capabilities of the storage engine to be effective}

The generation of primary key IDs is left to the reader, but something as simple as auto increment might give you a quick start [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html].

Which is better?

Unless this is a homework assignment, storing this kind of material in a classic RDBMS might not fit with contemporary idioms. Keep the same spiritual schema and use something like SOLR/Elasticsearch to store your material and benefit from the content indexing since I trust that you'll want to avoid writing your own search engine? You can use something like sphinx [http://sphinxsearch.com] to index MySQL in an equal manner.

[*] Without some unconventional structuring of your schema, the amount of metadata and pressure on the underlying filesystem will be problematic (for example some dated/legacy storage engines, like MyISAM on MySQL will create three files per table).

Answer (score 3):

You're better off having one table for comments, with a field that identifies which post id each comment belongs to. It will be a lot easier to write queries to get comments for a given post id if you do this, as you won't first need to dynamically determine the name of the table you're looking in.

I can only speak for MySQL here (not sure how this works in Postgresql) but make sure you add an index on the post id field so the queries run quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When working with relational databases, you have to understand (a little bit about) normalization. The [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (3NF) is easy to understand and works in almost any case. A short tutorial can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/third-normal-form.htm). Use Google if need more/other/better examples.

One table per record is a red light, you know you're missing something. It also means you need dynamic DDL, you must create new tables when you have new records. This is also a security issue, the database user needs to many permissions and  becomes a security risk.